# How to not target anchor tags in side navigation and top navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pop-up that will appear whenever a external link appears. If it is not an external link, the link should open in a new tab. The issue I am encountering is that this approach targets the anchor tags in the navigation bar and opens the page in a new tab. This should only occur for pdf documents and so on.

The following is my logic that detects whether it is a an external link or not. I am having a hard time to ignore the links that are in my navigation bar and the side navigation bar as well.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("a:not('.frontEndToolsModal')").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
        host = location.host;               

    if (url.indexOf(host) > -1 || url.indexOf('http','https') == -1){
        /* If we find the host name within the URL,
           OR if we do not find http or https, 
           meaning it is a relative internal link.

           The following statements is to not interefere with Mura CMS front end tools
        */

        if(url.indexOf('/admin/?muraAction=cArch.list') == 0){
            var newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
            newTab.focus();
        }
        else if(url.indexOf('/admin/?muraAction') == 0){
            //do nothing
        }else{                          
            var newTab2 = window.open(url, '_blank');
            newTab2.focus();
        }
    }
```

For the navigation bar, they have the following structure:

```
<ul id="navPrimary" class="nav navbar-nav nav-nowrap">

        <li class="first" id="navAboutUs"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

and for the side navigation bar, it has the following html:

```
<nav id="navStandard" class="mura-nav-standard well">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">

    <li class="first"><a href="#">Medical Services Authorization Status Tracker</a></li>
```

My question is: How can not include the side navigation and top navigation bars in my click function?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by using attr() and checking if the anchor tag contains "target='_blank'".

So I did the following:

```
if($(this).attr("target") != '_blank'){
    window.location.href = url;
}
else{
    var newTab1 = window.open(url, '_blank');
    newTab1.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$("a:not('.frontEndToolsModal')").on('click', function(e){
  // stuff happens
}
```

...is saying "a click on any `a` element that does have class `frontEndToolsModal`... stuff happens.

This means all the a links on your site besides the ones with that class. This is probably too broad of a selector for your click function. The real solution here is to figure out a different selector that works for the items that when clicked you DO WANT that function to run. This means likely adding some new class to those items you want to trigger the function and update the JS accordingly:

```
$("a.someNewClass").on('click', function(e){
  // stuff happens
}
```

Comment: I believe it is saying "a click on any a element that does not have class frontEndToolsModal". Yes you are correct it is too broad however a majority of anchor tags do not have classes. To do your approach, I would need to go to every page. Currently, it works fine and additional logic has been added. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @INSGUEST it is necessary as a project becomes large to have clear ways to target things specifically. Consider you can also target things based on their context, like what container the `a` link in in: `$(".one-container a").on('click', function() { ...do stuff });` and then `$(".another-container a").on('click', function() { ...do other stuff });`

Comment: Yes, you are correct once again. I advise this concern with the Marketing team on future content they may add on the site.